# WP-Admin not reachable

Tags: wp-admin

I added a wp_die message ("it works") to the functions.php of my child theme for testing. After that, the wp-admin and the frontend was no longer accessible, but it comes only the wp_die message from me "it works". I then changed the file not as before via wp-admin, but directly via FTP and removed the line with the wp_die function. The frontend was then accessible again, but wp-admin still not. I despair here slowly and hope someone has an idea what I can still try. You can access the page here: https://www.institute4languages.com and wp-admin here https://www.institute4languages.com/wp-admin

Comment: Still showing "it works" here, 4 hours later.  If you have removed the `wp_die()` statement via FTP and hours have passed, contact your web host for support.

Comment: Yes, I have already done that. The answer from the host: We have nothing to do with it and it's not us. -.- 

Is it possible that a plugin could cause such an error? I have already tried to deactivate the plugins on the FTP page (renamed subfolder of the plugin folder). However, I do not see any effect.

Comment: Looks at though you are still having trouble.  Change the theme for the site to a WP default theme.  That will eliminate any code you have modified in the child theme.  https://help.one.com/hc/en-us/articles/115005585909-Change-your-WordPress-theme-from-the-database

Comment: Even this approach does not bring anything. Neither when I change something on the FTP level, nor via the database. I have also tried to disable all plugins via the database (active_plugins a:0{}) it shows no effect at all. I wonder if a plugin like w3 total cache (is installed) can be responsible for this? I feel like I'm going crazy here :D

Comment: If you have removed the code the caused the problem, caching is the only thing that explains it.  Hopefully you can reach a more competent support rep with your host.  They are likely doing some caching, using a CDN, etc and perhaps your `wp_die()` mistake has caused these to fail their regular refresh schedule.

Comment: After I have now more than annoyed the host, it came out that he only provides the DNS server and forwards to another host. And what was? Caching!! He has now switched off and the page runs again. Thanks for your support 

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the error persists in the frontend. You think that the admin side is cached, but on the contrary, the front side is cached. You don't see errors on your homepage because it's cached. But all your pages are giving error. So you have to make sure you remove the correct code. Maybe you couldn't update properly via ftp.

Add any query to bypass cache on the front:
https://www.institute4languages.com/?asd